# Using importHTML with a php populated website and scraping to googlesheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping, import, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to import data from this website using importHTML into a googlesheet https://web.atanet.org/onlinedirectories/tsd_view.php?id=20508

I want to scrape the part that says "Mukilteo WA 98275"

Currently my imput is this: "=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://web.atanet.org/onlinedirectories/tsd_view.php?id=20508","table",2),2,2)"

It returns: N/A ie.("Imported Content is Empty")

It does not look like a case of dynamic website since I could not find any javascript running unless I missed something. What am I missing here?